# For each add white pace while featching media image

Tags: magento-1.9, media-images

This My Code

```
$IsCustomizableColor =  $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('customizecolor')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
   <?php 
$SplitColor = explode (',', $IsCustomizableColor);
foreach($SplitColor as $color){?>
 <?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'Custom/'.$color.'.png'; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

it will print with space for second time first time it's fine

**my output**

```
http://localhost/Test/media/Custom/Black.png 
http://localhost/Test/media/Custom/ Green.png 
http://localhost/Test/media/Custom/ Yellow.png
```

what is the problem? How to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this :

```
$IsCustomizableColor =  $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('customizecolor')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
   <?php 
$SplitColor = explode (',', $IsCustomizableColor);
foreach($SplitColor as $color){?>
 <?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'Custom/'.trim($color).'.png'; ?>
<?php } ?>
```